# int array initialization in java

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

correct[], student[], and numIncorrect have already been initialized but missedArray keeps showing as an empty arrray.

```
public static int[] missedArray(char[] correct, char[] student, int numIncorrect)
{
   int[] missedArray = new int[numIncorrect];
   for( int i = 0, j = 0; i < correct.length; i++)
   {
       if (student[i] != correct[i])
       {
       missedArray[j] = i+1;
       j++;
       }
   }
   return missedArray;
```

Comment: how you call this method?

Comment: The data that is passed in is important.

Comment: missedArray[] = missedArray(correct, student, numIncorrect)

Comment: @JoshTell what are the values for `correct`, `student`, `numIncorrect`? That's the important part in this question

Comment: correct[] = {a,b,c,d,e} student[] = {a,b,c,c,c} numIncorrect = 2

Comment: @Josh Your numIcorrect is correct? It will out of bound of the array size

Comment: Youm might be passing numIncorrect as zero. Check calling method area!

Comment: With those values `correct[] = {a,b,c,d,e} student[] = {a,b,c,c,c} numIncorrect = 2`  you will get resulting array has two elements.

Comment: I'm trying to display an array to show at what positions the other arrays don't match, but i keep getting [I@355d56d5

Comment: It worked for me. Can you show how you are calling it? numIncorrect would ideally be calculated inside the function.

Comment: @JoshTell-you are not printing the array correctly

Comment: @JoshTellCosider using this code: `int[] result = missedArray(correct, student, numIncorrect);
  for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(result[i]);
  }`

Comment: @hemath I displayed numIncorrect in missedArray() and it was 2, so its not that

Comment: @NavishSharma thats showing me  1 1

Answer (score -1):

it is working fine.Here is the code which i tried.

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char []c={'a','b','c','d','e'};
        char []s={'a','b','c','c','c'};
   int a[]= missedArray(c,s,2);
   for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
   {
       System.out.println(a[i]);
   }
    }
    public static int[] missedArray(char[] correct, char[] student, int numIncorrect)
    {
       int[] missedArray = new int[numIncorrect];
       for( int i = 0, j = 0; i < correct.length; i++)
       {
           if (student[i] != correct[i])
           {
           missedArray[j] = i+1;
           j++;
           }
       }
       return missedArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a real question and this answer won't make any difference. Not to provide an answer will be the better option.